# ruby on rails - ultrasphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, sphinx, ultrasphinx

Ruby on Rails - UltraSphinx

Hi guys, I'm using Ultrasphinx for the search thing.

My question is : I have the "rake ultrasphinx:daemon:start" running in the background. Now, should I have a cron job that does "rake ultrasphinx:index" regularly or will the daemon take care of indexing whenever a new object is created.

Please, let me know. Its kind of emergency.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to run a cron job to regularly update your index. However, you can run the rake task `ultrasphinx:index:delta` to only update the delta index which contains recently changed records.

From time to time, you might also want to merge your delta index into your main index using the task `ultrasphinx:index:merge`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your model if you want to use delta indexing:

```
is_indexed :fields => ['column1', 'column2'], :delta => true
```

1. Run ultrasphinx daemon:

   rake ultrasphinx:daemon:start
2. Add to your CRON(I run it every 10 mins, but final decision is all up to your app):
   rake ultrasphinx:index:delta
3. You will need to run rake *ultrasphinx:index:main* once a day to move the delta contents into the main index.

Source: [official documentation](http://blog.evanweaver.com/files/doc/fauna/ultrasphinx/files/README.html).

Comment: Hi Nikita, don't you think - the task to be run every 10 minutes is rake ultrasphinx:index:delta